# Jquery dialog box resize handle obscures and blocks the scrolldown button on the scrollbar,

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, resize, scrollbar

Perhaps someone might have an answer to this.

I have implemented the JQuery dialog box, works great. However when I have too much content in, which triggers the scrollbar and resize handle, the resize handle obscures the scrollbar down button.

This is even the case on the [documentation/demo website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) .

Is there a way to set an offset value or this is just the way it is or has to be?

Cheers

EDIT: This happens in IE7, Chrome and FF4.0.1

Comment: In which browser are you trying it?

Comment: I can verify that what blueRace is saying happens in FF4.0.1.  Seems to be a bug.

Comment: GOT IT! Edit .ui-dialog-content by adding right and bottom margins e.g. margin-right:.2em; margin-bottom:.5em; this moves the slider to the left and up. And you can choose to move the resize handle slightly by editing ui-resizable-se e.g. right: -1px; bottom: 0px;. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Tweak the CSS, you can add padding to .ui-widget-content to get around this.

Comment: actually editing .ui-dialog-content with FireBug in FF gives the desired results however editing the actually CSS file (css/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css) does nothing!  My solution for now is editing the right and bottom values of .ui-resizable-se, moving it ever so slightly.

Comment: I used this tecnique, but instead of editing the jquery css-file, I added the style to my own css. I had to make  sure that it was referenced after the jquery css file, so that my style would override the jquery style.

Comment: GOT IT! Edit .ui-dialog-content by adding right and bottom margins e.g. margin-right:.2em; margin-bottom:.5em; this moves the slider to the left and up. And you can choose to move the resize handle slightly by editing ui-resizable-se e.g. right: -1px; bottom: 0px;. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the height option and set a height if you know it before hand

or

Once the dialog is open just resize the height -

```
// note resizable option set to false
$("#dialogDIV").dialog({ resizable:false,    your-other-options-here    });

// This should get rid of the scrollbar
$("#dialogDIV").css("height","auto");
```

Comment: Can't have a fixed size as it is populated dynamically.